# ROS2 Galactic and Cyclone DDS with AWS machines - error in the configuration?

Tags: ros, ros2, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to use two AWS EC2 machines to the ROS2 Galactic robot simulation with Gazebo.

- First machine has more memory and is faster, there I want to start multirobot simulation with Gazebo.
- Second machine is simulating a robot computer with much less computing power and less memory, with Nav2 stack and other ROS nodes for control.

To use different machines I have to use properly configured Cyclone DDS. I tried to base my configuration on this tutorial:

https://husarion.com/tutorials/other-tutorials/husarnet-cyclone-dds/

But it doesn't work correctly (the whole situation is a bit weird too - description below).

I want to know why and how to fix it.

The end `cyclonedds.xml` is looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CycloneDDS xmlns="https://cdds.io/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://cdds.io/config https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds/master/etc/cyclonedds.xsd">
    <Domain id="any">
        <General>
            <NetworkInterfaceAddress>auto</NetworkInterfaceAddress>
            <AllowMulticast>true</AllowMulticast>
        </General>      
        <Discovery>
            <Peers>
                <Peer address="10.0.1.254"/>
                    <Peer address="10.0.1.148"/>
            </Peers>
        </Discovery>
    </Domain>
</CycloneDDS>
```

In my `~/.bashrc` I have both `export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_cyclonedds_cpp` and `export CYCLONEDDS_URI=file:///ros2_ws/src/cyclonedds/cyclonedds.xml` next to sourcing ROS2 Galaxy, `nav2_ws` and `ros2_ws`.

Something there isn't done correctly, because the end result I can observe is:

- after `ros2 launch nav2_bringup tb3_simulation_launch.py` Gazebo starts with RViz, I can see standard information from Nav2 launcher, except this part:

```
[gzserver-1] [WARN] [1646146379.323597688] [turtlebot3_laserscan]: New subscription discovered on topic '/scan', requesting incompatible QoS. No messages will be sent to it. Last incompatible policy: RELIABILITY_QOS_POLICY
[amcl-6] [WARN] [1646146379.417316916] [amcl]: New subscription discovered on topic '/particle_cloud', requesting incompatible QoS. No messages will be sent to it. Last incompatible policy: RELIABILITY_QOS_POLICY
```

- in the next terminal where I use SSH to connect to the machine number 1) I usually cannot list any of the topics (`ros2 topic list`) or nodes (`ros2 node list`); what is weird, I can see these topics and nodes on machine number 2) and only sometimes on machine number 1).

It looks like the ROS2 topics are hidden, but they are... Somwhere. Why cannot I detect them normally?

What mistakes have I made here? How can I fix them?

Relevant links I have found and tried to learn from them and solve this problems:

- https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Installation/DDS-Implementations.html
- https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Installation/DDS-Implementations/Working-with-Eclipse-CycloneDDS.html
- https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds/blob/master/docs/manual/config.rst
- https://www.infoq.com/articles/ros2-dds-communication/
- https://design.ros2.org/articles/ros_middleware_interface.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396922/ros2-galactic-and-cyclone-dds-with-aws-machines---error-in-the-configuration?/) by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3064 on 2022-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Switching to the Fast DDS and going with [it's documentation](https://fast-dds.docs.eprosima.com/en/latest/index.html) solved my problem, but if anyone could solve it with Cyclone DDS I will still be grateful.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1